# Returning Index of Row & Col in the Template Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, template-engine, indexof

I have a dynamic table which I created via `Handlebars.js` as template and the problem is I can't assign id to each cell representing their positions as row & col. I have the template below,

```
<script id="td-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each ships}}
    <tr>
        <td class='left-aligned'>{{this.name}}</td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{@index}}"></td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

which is returning 0 for first, 1 for second loop and vice versa. What I need is to add a formula instead of **{{@index}}** but it doesn't let me add like breaking the html or table itself when I intend to.

I'm open any suggestions like `JQuery` instead Handlebars.js

Comment: Why do you need this? It's generally less work (and easier to maintain) to just figure out the index of the element within it's event handlers. This negates the need to even have an `id` on the element.

Comment: I have a table for instance 5 rows to 3 columns table and trying to give each cell a unique id like 1,2,3,4, etc arbitrarily. I couldn't think of any solution to this but you may suggest any easier way if you know so..

Comment: The @index is a ship id / index from array of ships?

Comment: yes @Oskar, I tried with a for loop but couldn't implement it inside the template either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a helper function, something like this:

```
var columnsCount = 3; // change this to the total number of columns per row in your table.
Handlebars.registerHelper("multiply", function(index, count){
    return (index * columnsCount) + count;
});
```

and then set the IDs using something like this:

```
<script id="td-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each ships}}
    <tr>
        <td class='left-aligned'>{{this.name}}</td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{multiply @index 1}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{multiply @index 2}}"></td>
        <td class="default" id="id{{multiply @index 3}}"></td>
        .....
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here is a snipped showing this approach in action:

```js
var columnsCount = 3; // change this to the total number of columns per row in your table.
Handlebars.registerHelper("multiply", function(index, count){
    return (index * columnsCount) + count;
});

var context = {
  ships: [{
    name: 'ship one'
  }, {
    name: 'ship two'
  }]
};

$('#rendered').append(Handlebars.compile($("#td-template").html())(context));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="td-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {{#each ships}}
        <tr>
            <td class='left-aligned'>{{this.name}}</td>
            <td class="default" id="id{{multiply @index 1}}">column {{multiply @index 1}}</td>
            <td class="default" id="id{{multiply @index 2}}">column {{multiply @index 2}}</td>
            <td class="default" id="id{{multiply @index 3}}">column {{multiply @index 3}}</td>
            <!-- and so on.... -->
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</script>

<div id="rendered"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution! But I couldn't make it work properly. It might be because if there is any missing comma inside the curly braces? Or is there any extra step do I need to do besides adding your `registerHelper` function inside my `document.ready` function?

Comment: @ErhanYaşar I've edited my answer. There was an error in the way I was calculating the column's index. If you're going to use this approach, don't forget to change the `columnsCount` variable.

Comment: Actually it was mainly because of defining the Handlebars's `registerHelper` function inside my `document.ready()`. It worked after I changed its place and already edited similar as your edit.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar Great. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Well you did. Can I ask if you have any idea why it doesn't work inside of `document.ready()`? Cuz I defined all my variables inside of it and now if I have to define this registerHelper function out of it, then I have to use static columnsCount instead of `data.ships.lenght`.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar I'm not sure, maybe it has to do with the order you define the variables and functions. You have do define `Handlebars.registerHelper("multiply", ...)` before you call `Handlebars.compile`.

Comment: Ahaha yes indeed. Very much thanks again. I'll probably accept it as an answer after being sure if the other answer works or not since he replied first. Wish you a beautiful day buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use block params: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#block-params

Together with data attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Also to perform a arithmetic operation you have to define a helper: http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers

Plus I would move the `id` under the `tr` node:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("eval", function() {
  let args = Array.from(arguments);
  args.pop(); //remove the unwanted object from args list
  return eval(args.join(''));
});

var context = {
  ships: [{
    name: 'battleship',
    id: 1,
    column0: 'says',
    column1: 'hello',
    column2: 'world'
  }, {
    name: 'titanic',
    id: 2,
    column0: 'yields',
    column1: 'hi',
    column2: 'world'
  }]
};

$('#dropzone').append(Handlebars.compile($("#td-template").html())(context));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="td-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each ships as |ship i|}}
  <tr data-id="{{ship.id}}">
    <td class="left-aligned" data-id="{{eval i '*4' }}">{{ship.name}}</td>
    <td class="default" data-id="{{eval i '*4+1' }}">{{ship.column0}}</td>
    <td class="default" data-id="{{eval i '*4+2' }}">{{ship.column1}}</td>
    <td class="default" data-id="{{eval i '*4+3' }}">{{ship.column2}}</td> 
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  
</script>

<table id="dropzone"></table>
```

Then in order to obtain the id from tr node:

```
$(tr).data('id');
```

Comment: Thanks very much but, I asked mostly continuing count. I mean if the first row is "test 1, test 2, test 3" then the second row would be "test 4, test 5, test6" and so on. It's quite different though, I have either "id" with the ships itself. Do you have any other solution to this?

Comment: @ErhanYaşar I updated my answer, didn't catch at first that you need to accumulate values per row and per column

Comment: Well I have separate "shipID" besides "shipName" inside the context within ships. So my main objective was only getting acquaintance of table cells by assigning different ids which I'll call later on to manipulate on them. I'm adding these rows each time with the template for each column already. Your solution also solves the issue anyway but it needs assigning the column value inside `columnCount` statically each time. I even tried to find a dynamic way of writing   **columnCount: Array(5).fill(5)** but not found any. Do you have any idea??

Comment: @ErhanYaşar with `shipID` it's fine just replace `shipId` with `ship.shipId` I still don't get how you want to generate your columns, are they fields from each `ship` or you want to add them by hand?

Comment: I edited the question to be able to show you the case's smaller version. Your solution solves with a statical answer instead a dynamic way. Just appreciate and learned a new way if you can reproduce a way of thinking it.